# How can I assure that a View is available when I call a Fragment method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the native Android drawer for my menu, here in MainActivity :

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Home
                fragment = new EntryFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                //Journal
                fragment = new JournalFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                // Medications
                fragment = new RxFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                // Reminders
                fragment = new ReminderFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                // Counselor Locator
                fragment = new LocatorFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                // Library
                fragment = new LibraryFragment();
                break;
            case 6:
                // Settings
                break;
            case 7:
                // About
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(String.valueOf(position)).commit();
        String fragmentTitles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
        if(mActionBar != null) {
            mActionBar.setTitle(fragmentTitles[position]);
        }

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
```

But I'm repurposing EntryFragment for another activity (EntryDetailActivity), so in EntryFragment I defined a couple of methods to modify the view based on which activity is hosting it:

```
// Runs on the home page, shows/hides appropriate views
    public void prepareForHomeView() {

        mTxtDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mBtnDiffDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEdtNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mBtnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mBtnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    // Runs on the detail page, shows/hides appropriate views
    public void prepareForDetailView() {
        mBtnLog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

In EntryDetailActivity, I can easily call prepareForDetailView() in onResumeFragments(), but I'm having an issue of where to call prepareForHome() in MainActivity, since I am swapping fragments in and out based on the menu. Any suggestions?

/** Update **/
I assigned the fragments a tag that is the position of the menu through addToBackstack(). I also added the following method to my MainActivity:

```
    @Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    EntryFragment entryFrag = (EntryFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("0");

    if(entryFrag != null) {
        Log.v("rx", "Home frag is not null");
    } else {
        Log.v("rx", "Home frag is null");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity` (or `FragmentActivity`) has `onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)` - you could do an `instanceof` on `fragment` to determine if it is the correct type of fragment (or use the id, tag, etc) and call the appropriate method.

Alternatively, you could have the Fragment check the `getActivity()` (in `onCreateView` / `onViewCreated`).

Comment: Ok, good suggestions, and I tried the first one and updated the example code with some notes. Issue is that the fragment always comes back as null (and it runs once for every fragment, seems unnecessary but not harmful).

Comment: As far as the second suggestion, how does the fragment know which activity is hosting it in order to call the correct method?

Comment: For #1. Use the fragment that is passed into the method as a parameter. You can determine `if(fragment instanceof EntryFragment) { ((EntryFragment) fragment).prepareForHomeView(); }`

Comment: For #2. `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle instance) { super.onViewCreated(view, instance); if(getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) { prepareForHomeView(); } else { prepareForDetailView(); }

Comment: #3 - pass in the state the fragment should be displaying in the arguments of the fragment

#4 - create different classes which extend from a base fragment and instantiate the correct one.

#5 - have the activity implement an interface that the fragment knows about that determines which state it should be in

Comment: Cool, #1 works, stupid me I overlooked the fragment parameter in that method. And if you have the time (you don't have to go into a long explanation or anything) which of these suggestions are most flexible/preferable? Or is it just a matter of coding style?

Comment: #1 is 'ok' because it is the activity's responsibility to create the fragment, so it is reliable to know which types of fragments are going to be attached. #5 is better than #2 because the fragment shouldn't care about where it is used (shouldn't know the specific activities), some don't like this direction of data flow though (fragment asking for data it should given). #3 or #4 are probably better than #1 unless the same instance of the fragment needs to be able to switch back and forth between the different states. #4 is probably overkill for small tweaks determinable by a single argument.